# If i increase max_excecution_time wil loading time will increase or decrease?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php with codeigniter framework. I have a problem in my project that is related to execution time. So, we increased the `max_execution_time` from server side. But now my problem is if i am uploading a small data to the server it will take a long time to load. Is there any problem with `max_execution_time` ? If we  increase that `max_execution_time` then that loading time also increased? Please help me. If the problem with `max_execution_time` then we will decrease that.

Comment: So... You set your application to allow for longer execution times, and now you're asking why it allows longer execution times?  Sorry, it's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: The `max_execution` directive just allows the script to run for at most X seconds. It doesn't require the script to run for that length. http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: When we are uploading the data it will takes a long time.I think it is due to increasing the max_execution_time in server. Is it right sir?

Comment: It could be, previously you would have received a maximum execution error in your error logs. Did you find that, or if you revert the setting does it time out with a fatal error?

Comment: Yes, previously i have faced the problem with timeout error.

Comment: Is this impact on loading time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `max_execution_time` does NOT increase the time it takes to execute scripts. It only changes the amount of time a script is allowed to attempt to execute. It should not have any effect on the actual time it takes to execute your scripts. If your file upload seems to be taking longer now, it's just a coincidence.